# Pronunciation of "scone"

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, dialects

The argument about the pronunciation of *[scone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scone)*:-

> skoʊn, skɒn
>   noun 
>   1. a small, light, biscuitlike quick bread made of oatmeal, wheat flour, barley meal, or the like.

reappeared in the pub last night, as usual with no-one being able to produce a convincing argument about which of *skoʊn* or *skɒn* was correct. So I'd like to know, is there any historical or etymological reason for one to be preferred to the other?

In my travels up and down the country I have heard it both ways whereever I have lived, but is there a regional or geographic divide for the pronunciation? Do non-British English speakers also have this argument?

Comment: *We're resigned to our differences over the pronunciation of 'scone' (rhyming it with either 'stone' or 'gone'). The strange thing is that both of us regard the other's pronunciation as sounding 'posh'. So, does scone/scone divide along class lines, or is it more about geography or something else?*  (http://ask.metafilter.com/225418/You-say-scone-I-say-scone-lets-call-the-whole-thing-off)

Comment: See also: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/03/how-do-you-say-scone/ http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkeIGP5gUy8 (Hehe!) http://virtuallinguist.typepad.com/the_virtual_linguist/2010/05/the-pronunciation-of-scone.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scone http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scone  http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060810095051AAHuwR4

Comment: @Kris - That articl was written by someone very cunning ;)

Comment: *I asked the maid in dulcet tone\ To order me a buttered scone\ 
The silly girl has been and gone\ And ordered me a buttered scone.* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scone)

Comment: Appropos nothing (except the Scottish connection).  I remember my late grandmother, a Cockney who married a Scot, telling of the time she walked into a butcher's shop in Kearny, New Jersey, and she heard a customer ask for "a punna links."  She then told us, with a chuckle, what the customer was asking for.  An "upvote for useful comment" to the first person who guesses correctly what the customer was asking for.

Comment: By the way, my grandmother in the above comment baked scones regularly as I was growing up.  For what it's worth, her pronunciation rhymed with gone.

Comment: A pound of sausages?

Comment: @BraddSzonye:  You win!  The award is in the mail!  Don't spend it all in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Online Etymology Dictionary:

> scone (n.) - "thin, flat cake," 1510s, Scottish, probably shortened from Dutch *schoon brood* "fine bread," from Middle Dutch *schoonbroot*, from *schoon*, *scone* "bright, beautiful" (see sheen) + *broot* (see bread (n.)).

It should be noted that the word *schoon* in Dutch has taken on the meaning of the English adjective "clean". The pronunciation of *schoon*, linked below to its Google Translate page, rhymes with *bone*. I would conclude, then, that the "long 'o'" variation of *scone* is the correct one, etymologically speaking.

References:

> Etymology - http://etymonline.com/?term=scone
>
> Translation/pronunciation - http://translate.google.com/#en/nl/clean

Comment: It’s more complex than that, I’m afraid. The somewhat diphthongal pronunciation of the Modern Dutch digraph ‹oo› is newer than Middle Dutch (where it would more likely just have been [oː]), and in the 14–1500s, a long /oː/ in English was also pronounced vastly different from the diphthong we have today. I would venture that the [oː] sound of Middle Dutch probably sounded more like a short /o/ to some English-speaking people when they borrowed it, and more like long /oː/ to others; hence the dichotomy.

Comment: (And incidentally, the same word has in the Northern Germanic languages taken on the meaning of ‘lovely/beautiful’)